# how to get the output in the same column in sql?

Tags: mysql, sql-server

i am new to this sql. i just want to ask doubt regarding sql.( am using sql server 2012)

two tables:

states:

select * from [dbo].[States]

```
StateId    StateName

    1       Odisha

    2      West Bengal

    3      Bihar

    4      Jharkhand
```

district:  select * from [dbo].[Districts]

```
DistrictId          StateId         DistrictName

1                    1                 Mayurbhanj

2                     1                 Keonjhar

3                     1                 Khorda

4                     1                 Balasore

5                     2                 Hoogly

6                     2                 Howrah

7                     2                 Jalpaiguri

8                     3                 Aurangabad

9                     3                 Patna

10                    4                 Bokaro
```

i have tried this join query

select s.StateName, d.DistrictName from states s join Districts d on s.stateid=d.stateid

and got output like this

```
  stateName         districtName

   Odisha             Mayurbhanj

   Odisha             Keonjhar

   Odisha             Khorda

   Odisha             Balasore

   West Bengal        Hoogly

   West Bengal        Howrah

   West Bengal        Jalpaiguri

   Bihar              Patna

   Jharkhand          Bokaro 

   Bihar              Aurangabad
```

but i want output like this

```
 Odisha             //statename
 Mayurbhanj   
 Keonjhar           //district names
 Khorda
 Balasore 
 West Bengal        //statename        
 Hoogly
 Howrah
 Jalpaiguri
 Bihar              //statename 
 Aurangabad
 Patna
 Jharkhand          //statename
 Bokaro
```

in a same column....

is it possible to do using query or store procedure?? please help me to sort it out

Comment: Which database you are using..SQL Server or MySQL? Please don't tag products which you are not using!

Comment: Personally I would not use SQL to do this kind of formatting, but rather the application in which you want to present this data. Why do you want the output like that / how are you presenting the data to your user / what application?

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to do it in SQL, here is one way using `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT Name
FROM (
    SELECT 0 AS DistrictId, StateId, StateName AS Name FROM states
    UNION ALL
    SELECT *  FROM district
)AS t
ORDER BY StateId, DistrictId
```

Comment: it worked out @Felix   thank you. but what kind of concept you are using here?

Comment: What do you mean concept? You just combine all the rows of both table using `UNION ALL` and then `ORDER BY StateId, DistrictId`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using php, you can use main query to populate states with while loop. Then add another sub query to populate districts under each state, using another while loop inside the main loop. I hope this will help you to get it. Regards !

Answer (score 0):

You can use `GROUP_CONCAT`  if you want to get the result in a single Query

```
SELECT s.StateName
    ,GROUP_CONCAT(d.DistrictName)
FROM states s
INNER JOIN district d ON s.StateId = d.StateId
GROUP BY s.StateId
```

Comment: if i run this query i got error like this      "'GROUP_CONCAT' is not a recognized built-in function name."

Comment: You can use this method if you are using sql server 2012 " SELECT STUFF(
             (SELECT ',' + Column_Name 
              FROM Table_Name
              FOR XML PATH (''))
             , 1, 1, '') "